# can any one give me the url's where i get best sample code for iphone as well as iPad applications?

Tags: iphone

i am working as iPhone Application Developer.I want to Learn new things in iphone so please guiding me i want some sample code as well as some Tutorials so i get proper knowledge.Please help me....

Comment: This is a site for asking programming-related questions. In my opinion, this is stretching the limit, and could be considered a subjective question (moderators - note the use of "best").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [iCode Blog](http://icodeblog.com/) has a lot of good tutorials.

Comment: Here you get rss feed:=> http://in.reuters.com/tools/rss

Answer (score 0):

http://adeem.me/blog/ is a good website for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of sample codes are available from [Apple iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action). You may need to register to access them.

Comment: I guess the access to the codes and tutorial don't require a registration fee. Though I'm not 100% sure.